# custom drawing portion of image .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, drawing, .net-4.5, system.windows.media

I am custom drawing two zoom-in images on the screen, one next to each other. Each one of them occupies half of the screen.

I have previously done it in .net 3.5 (I think) by overriding the OnPaint():

```
    //using System.Drawing

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom drawing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, DestRectangle, SrcRectangle, GraphicsUnit);
    }
```

The description of the DrawImage method: "Draws the specified portion of the specified Image at the specified location and with the specified size." ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx))

I am trying to achieve the same thing using .net 4.5. I am overriding the OnRender and using the DrawingContext object to perform my drawings. Basically this is my loop:

```
    //using System.Windows.Media;

    /// <summary>
    /// Overide the OnRender to have access to a lower level of drawing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="drawingContext"></param>
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapImage_Left, Window_LeftHalf);
        drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapImage_Right, Window_RightHalf);
    }
```

It works just fine if I want to display the stretched picture. What I want is to display (in Window_LeftHalf and Window_RightHalf) a portion of the picture (like zoom-in). Basically what graphics.DrawImage (look above) does, but using the DrawingContext object.

I have tried to look at MSDN but I couldn't pull anything interesting out. Maybe creating a buffer that is later used by the DrawingContext? I'm almost sure there is the need for an intermediate object that holds the zoomed-in images. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I am using the mouse to navigate through the image, so performance *is* important. For example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the mouse move events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void MouseMoveEventHandler(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The size of the crop is always the same
        // but the portion of the picture different.
        crop.X += mouseDelta.X;
        crop.Y += mouseDelta.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `CroppedBitmap` class.  Just as you used to be able to do with `e.Graphics.DrawImage()`, `CroppedBitmap` allows you to specify just the portion of the image you're interested in.

Here's an example:

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
{
    int halfWidth = (int)this.Width / 2;
    int height = (int)this.Height;
    BitmapImage leftImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"));
    BitmapImage rightImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"));
    CroppedBitmap leftImageCropped = new CroppedBitmap(leftImage, new Int32Rect(0, 0, halfWidth, height));
    CroppedBitmap rightImageCropped = new CroppedBitmap(rightImage, new Int32Rect(0, 0, halfWidth, height));
    dc.DrawImage(leftImageCropped, new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, leftImageCropped.Width, height));
    dc.DrawImage(rightImageCropped, new System.Windows.Rect(halfWidth, 0, halfWidth, height));
}
```

Comment: Hey cokeman19, thank for reply. Yes! I havent tried it yet, but it looks just like the thing that I want. The only difference is that every time I need a new section of the image I need to create/ modify an CroppedBitmap object, where `e.Graphics.DrawImage()` would use the same bitmap all the time. Thanks anyway, I'll use it. I'll update my post to a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2** :
`ImageBrush.Viewbox`. The Viewbox is a `Rect` with dimensions [0.0... 1.0] that let you control what used to be the SourceRect. I tested this and it works brilliantly. What I did:

In my Window:

```
    protected ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush(new ImageSource(new Uri("image.png")));
    protected Rect vBox = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    protected Point lastPosition = new Point(0, 0);
```

My container for this was a WPF Rectangle called *tgtRect* whose `Rect.Fill` was *imgBrush*. The zoom and scroll methods were as follows:

```
    protected void tgtRect_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Zoom in when Delta is positive, Zoom out when negative
        double exp = -e.Delta / Math.Abs(e.Delta);
        double val = Math.Pow(1.1, exp);
        vBox.Scale(val, val);
        imgBrush.Viewbox = vBox;
    }

    void tgtRect_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point thisPosition = e.GetPosition(tgtRect);
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            double w = tgtRect.ActualWidth;
            double h = tgtRect.ActualHeight;
            Vector offset = lastPosition - thisPosition;
            offset.X /= w;
            offset.Y /= h;
            vBox.Offset(offset);
            imgBrush.Viewbox = vBox;
        }
        lastPosition = thisPosition;
    }
```

For your implementation:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(imgBrush, null, DesRect);
    }
```

You will likely need to maintain a separate imgBrush for each rectangle you want to draw to. I tried the above code (not the OnRender override) in a WPF Window with just a Rectangle whose `Rectangle.Fill` was this `ImageBrush` and the performance was very good. If you have any troubles, I think we can sort it out, but I think the ImageBrush will end up being the correct implementation. This has been a very interesting project! Thank you for your question.

**END EDIT 2**

You will need to define the `Rect` objects "Window_LeftHalf" and "Window_RightHalf"     to be the actual size you want the images to be rendered. For example, if you are zoomed 200%, then the `Rect.Width` and `Rect.Height` properties will need to be 2x the size of the original ImageSource.

**EDIT**:

Old method was :

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, DestRectangle, SrcRectangle, GraphicsUnit);
}
```

Using 'BitmapImage.SourceRect` :

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    BitmapImage_Left.SourceRect = SrcRectangleLeft;
    drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapImage_Left, Window_LeftHalf);
    BitmapImage_Right.SourceRect = SrcRectangleRight;
    drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapImage_Right, Window_RightHalf);
}
```

Your mouse functions can change the SourceRect. For example:

```
private static void MouseMoveEventHandler(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The size of the crop is always the same
    // but the portion of the picture different.
    SrcRectangleLeft = new Int32Rect(SrcRectangleLeft.X + mouseDelta.X, 
        SrcRectangleLeft.Y + mouseDelta.Y,
        SrcRectangleLeft.Width, SrcRectangleLeft.Height);
}
```

Not sure how the performance will be, but should be better than mapping portions of the bitmap onto new objects each update.

Hope this has helped at all.

Comment: Hey newb, thanks for reply. I had tried it before. If I do that the images will overlap. Even if I display them in the right spot, the Window_*Half will not display the *specific* parts of the images (zoomed).

Comment: That would make sense if you're not repositioning the target rectangles. I'm re-reading this and imagining side-by-side scrolling windows for each half of the window. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, side by side, fixed "windows." But the content is always changing. So if I display 200% I can only have a fixed content (on x-axis).

Comment: Ok. I think I might have another solution. If your BitmapImage_Left and BitmapImage_Right are indeed BitmapImage objects, you can set their BitmapImage.SourceRect property based on the position and zoom. I'll edit the original answer with an example.

Comment: If the SourceRect is the area of the image that is to be considered, than I think this is the answer. I don't know how I completely missed this. I haven't checked this yet but I'll surely come back here if it didn't worked. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, there is a little problem here. The `BitmapImage.SourceRect` property can't be changed on demand. Or at leas this is what I understood ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) The 'Remarks' section). If there is a way than this is a valid solution, otherwise I'm going to stick with `CroppedBitmap`.

Comment: I was just looking through a solution where I had to do something similar recently (cropping images, technically visuals, for printing a dynamic UI), and there I used Brushes. One more edit! I promise this is going to be a perfect solution!

Comment: I couldn't figure it out how to change the properties on demand. I'll stick with creating new `CroppedBitmap`. It seems to pop the CPU a bit to much for what it does, but I'll just stick to it for the moment. Thanks (both) for the input.